# A question on a symmetric derivative

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f:J→\mathbb R$ is a function on an open interval $J$ satisfying following inequality:
$∣f(x)+f(y)−2f(\frac{x+y}{2})∣≤C(f)|x−y|^{1+\delta}$
for all $x,y\in J,$ and for some $\delta \in(0,1]$.

Does it follow from this fact that $f∈C^1$ or $C^{1+δ}$?